# Deployed Spider on Heroku: Where are the downloaded files saved at?

Tags: email, emailfileattachment

I am new to web-scraping and deployment of spiders.

1. Basically, I am in the midst of creating a spider to scrape some items and download Excel files from a website
2. I want to schedule the spider on Heroku to send an email with the downloaded files.

From https://github.com/yashashreesuresh/amaz...ce_tracker, I know we can use smtplib to let the spider send email.

As the file system for Heroku is ephemeral, so if the spider click some button on the website to trigger a file download, where will the file be saved? I will need the file path to attach it to the email.

(For a human Download, when the Download is clicked, the file will auto-download to the "Download" folder on the local computer)

Thank you.

Comment: It'll go somewhere on the Heroku ephemeral filesystem, but _where_ is entirely dependent on the behavior of the software you are using. For that reason, this question isn't answerable by the community as written and may be closed; please [edit] if you wish to add specific details (see [ask] and [help/on-topic]).

Comment: @David Reed: Then is there some way, I can find where the file will be in the filesystem? I can't find any answers to my query in the Internet. And Heroku support directed me to this forum